# avoiding the junk email folders for important email notifications

Tags: javascript, asp.net, email, gmail, html-email

I have created a login system that sends activation email to the user. Now the problem is that the email goes to junk folders mostly. That is terrible issue. `http://blog.kissmetrics.com/avoid-the-spam-folder/` checked this link. But want any expert advice here . Is there any straight way to avoid this junk folder.

Comment: It's fairly standard practice to notify the user of the email address that you intend to contact them from and to request them to whitelist it so that the spam folder is circumvented.

Comment: If it is going to junk folders, chances are that either your IP or content is flagging it as spam.

Comment: ok... so it means there is no programming way or so other way where I can fix it???

Comment: Unless you count changing your email code as programming, then no. If you try sending a plain text email without large money figures, exclamation points (these are considered spammy) and it still goes in the spam folder, chances are that it is your IP or domain being flagged, which is a bad thing.

Comment: The body the mail is usually HTML to handle the links back to the website.. is that bad?? @John

Comment: No, that is normal. I was suggesting just text as to rule content out as a cause when troubleshooting the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, check that the DNS of the server forwards and reverses correctly.  If not, most spam filters will not consider your server to be a 'real' mail server, and will most likely flag any message sent from your server as spam.  This is how many spam filters block spam that originates from computers that have been taken over as 'zombies'.

For example, consider a message received from a mail server at 209.85.160.173 (which happens to be a Gmail mail server).  A spam filter on the receiving end might check to see if this is likely a 'real' mail server by doing a reverse DNS lookup on 209.85.160.173.  This resolves to mail-gh0-f173.google.com.  Then, if you do a DNS lookup of mail-gh0-f173.google.com, you get 209.85.160.173, which is the original IP.  So, that's right.  Make sure the DNS of your mail server forwards and reverses correctly like this.  Also, make sure that the name that your mail server uses to identify itself (in the HELO or EHLO command) resolves to the IP of the mail server.

Another thing to do is to check that you mail server IP is not on any blacklists.  You can use MXToolbox for this: http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Another thing you can do is use port25's verifier tool.  This tool will spot any red flags that might be causing your messages to be flagged as spam.  See http://www.port25.com/support/authentication-center/email-verification/ for more info.

Last but not least, you might want to setup an SPF record for the domain that you are sending these messages from, to indicate that the IP of your mail server is authorized to send mail from this domain.  This will help a lot.  For more info, see: www.openspf.org.